# Open default browser when link opens a new window

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using Android WebView and I have `shouldoverrideurlloading` so that it doesn't open up the default browser when navigating within the browser.

Is there a way to get it so it only opens the default browser when the link is one that opens a new page like: target="_blank"??